# create a link to a random post within the current category

Tags: query

I've got some code which creates a nice link to a random post - any way to amend it so that on a category page it selects a post from the current category?

thanks,

```
<?php
$randomPost = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT guid FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
echo '<a href="'.$randomPost.'">Random Post</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function. You can change the number of posts that you want. I set the category id if you're in a category page.

```
<?php
    rewind_posts() ;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand') ;
    $exclude_posts = array() ;
    if ( have_posts() ) { 
        while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
            $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID() ;
        }
    }
    $args['exclude'] = $exclude_posts ;
    if( is_category() ) {
        $args['category'] = get_query_var('cat') ;
    }
    $rand_posts = get_posts( $args ) ;
    foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">Random Post</a>';
    }
    rewind_posts() ;
?>
```

I hope it helps you :-)

**UPDATE** Now exclude the posts showed in this page

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. I'm never going to need more than one post - it's literally a link to a random post. I also need it to dynamically recognise the post of the current category thats displaying - this doesn't seem to do that... sorry!

Comment: What do you mean with "I also need it to dynamically recognise the post of the current category thats displaying". Usually, there are more than one post displaying in the current category.

Comment: I've just modified the first answer, excluding the post id's showed in the same page.

Comment: sorry - typing in a hurry to leave the office - I meant recognise the current category - not the current post - my bad!

Comment: still doesn;t seem to grab only posts from the current category - it seems anything goes - also - the original thing I post was almost there - and seems simpler - i ther not a way to simply add in a variable to only pick from the current category?

Comment: Try to comment this code:
    `$exclude_posts = array() ;
    if ( have_posts() ) { 
        while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
            $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID() ;
        }
    }
    $args['exclude'] = $exclude_posts ;` I was having some troubles because I had only a few posts. However, definitely it's working fine this piece of code if you comment those lines.